# How to make an image appear cyclically on each click with p5js

Tags: javascript

I am new to the amazing world of creative coding and p5js. I want to create a website for my design studio with a p5js effect that I can't find the solution for. I searched everywhere and I can't find anyone with the same problem as me, that's why I'm posting my very first message here. 
Here's the idea: in a canvas, I would like that with each mouse click, a different image can appear. Currently, my code allows to display images randomly but I would like to be able to set a cyclic order of appearance : work0.png, work1.png, work2.png... and it starts again.

If someone has seen this problem somewhere or could explain it to me I would be very grateful. Thanks !

```js
let works = []

function preload() {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    works[i] = loadImage("work" + i + ".png")
  }
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function draw() {
cursor(CROSS);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  let r = floor(random(0, 6));
      image(works[r], mouseX, mouseY, 500, 600);
}
```

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... please ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: @jsotola while the answer might be pretty simple i think it's an answerable question

Comment: Consider editing your question to summarize with a specific question pertaining to your goal. I suggest this: "How can I get JavaScript code to display one image after a mouse click event so that a set of images are displayed in cyclic display order and then reset?"

Answer (score 1):

instead of using random, you can use a counter

```js
let works = []

function preload() {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    works[i] = loadImage("work" + i + ".png")
  }
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function draw() {
cursor(CROSS);
}

var counter = 0
function mouseClicked() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  counter++    //add one to the counter
  image(works[counter%5], mouseX, mouseY, 500, 600); // the % symbols is modulo, which is a fancy word for remainder when divided by that number, so it would cycle from 0 to 4
}
```

So the counter starts at zero, and every time you click we increase the counter by one. to stop it from increasing constantly, we can use the modulo operator %(in programming this isn't the percent sign). examples: 2%5 is 2, 16%5 is 1, 25%5 is 0.

this essentially makes the value cycle from 0 to 4. the counter is constantly increasing, but the remainder when divided by five will always cycle.

also btw p5.js is a javascript library, and you are loading in code made by other people, which means without the p5.js library the code doesn't run in this code snippet on StackOverflow